# CNTK Cant load fastRCNN in wsgi with apache on windows

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, cntk

I've been trying to deploy a `cntk` model on windows with wsgi and apache.

I've got the flask server running locally and able to get results but when I try to deploy the same with apache and WSGI, it just doesn't load up.

I've tried loading an empty app in WSGI and Apache and it worked so I'm sure there's no issue with the setup, however, when I use apache, the app doesn't load up at all.

From what I could gather, wsgi is trying to load up all the libraries, one of which is fastRCNN which is locally compiled and not available in python libs.

When I comment out the import line which is importing fastRCNN, the app loads with errors such as CNTK not found.

Question: 
  Why is `fastRCNN` not importing ?

Here's what I have in my wsgi file

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler

# Get app root, directory of .wsgi file
app_root = os.path.dirname(__file__)

command = ['activate', 'C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows- x86_64\envs\cntk-py35']   
# Add app root to path for imports
sys.path.insert(0, app_root)

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
os.environ['PATH'] += r'"C:\cntk\cntk;"'

python_version = sys.version_info

# Import the app
from appName import app as application
```

Apache conf:

```
LoadFile "c:/local/anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64/envs/cntk-py35/python35.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/local/anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64/envs/cntk-py35/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/local/anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64/envs/cntk-py35"

<VirtualHost *:80 >
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}         
  WSGIScriptAlias /app "C:/PATH/TO/app.wsgi"
  ServerName example.com    
  <Directory "C:/PATH/TO/App/">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the link to the code - https://github.com/Azure/ObjectDetectionUsingCntk

If I comment line no 11 in this file  https://github.com/Azure/ObjectDetectionUsingCntk/blob/master/helpers.py, the app loads but with errors.

as per the suggestion, I updated apache config and now I get these errors:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=4180): Target WSGI script 'C:/PATH/TO/App.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=4180): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/PATH/TO/App.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r
 File "c:\\local\\anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py35\\lib\\site-packages\\cntk\\cntk_py.py", line 18, in swig_i

 return importlib.import_module(mname)\r
 File "c:\\local\\anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py35\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\

  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
  ImportError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'\r
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r
  Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File "C:/PATH/TO/App.wsgi", line 20, in <module>\r
  from App import app as application\r
  File "C:/PATH/App\\App.py", line 3, in <module>\r
  from helpers_cntk import *\r
  File "C:/PATH/App\\helpers_cntk.py", line 9, in <module>\r
  from cntk import *\r
  File "c:\\local\\anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py35\\lib\\site-packages\\cntk\\__init__.py", line 10, in <modu

  from . import cntk_py\r
  File "c:\\local\\anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py35\\lib\\site-packages\\cntk\\cntk_py.py", line 21, in <modul_cntk_py = swig_import_helper()\r
  File "c:\\local\\anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py35\\lib\\site-packages\\cntk\\cntk_py.py", line 20, in swig_i

  return importlib.import_module('_cntk_py')\r
  File "c:\\local\\anaconda3-4.1.1-windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py35\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\

  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.\r
```

These errors could perhaps be because of conda env not being setup and I'm not sure if I have the conda env setup right in wsgi script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for how to set up Python virtual environment. Avoid using activate method on Windows. Use ``WSGIPythonHome`` instead in Apache configuration.

Comment: I don't use virtualenv, I have anaconda installed which sets up the python env.  How do I activate a conda env in python script ? Is this the same as activating a virtualenv ? I'm new to python so please forgive my silly questions.

Comment: Updated my apache conf. @GrahamDumpleton can you help me activate conda env in python script ?

Comment: Add ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`` to your Apache configuration.

Comment: Yes now the app loads up but with error. I'm updating my questions with the error.

Comment: Sorry for the botheration, it works now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Setting WSGApplicationGroup Helped. I also had to update my path vars to point the current python version. Thank you @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: The ``WSGIApplicationGroup`` is required as some third party packages for Python with C extensions aren't implemented such that they work in Python sub interpreters. This makes it necessary to ensure they run in the main interpreter context, which is what that directive does. More details in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api